# Access VBA integration with Word slow using Office 365

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office365

MS Access application integrates with Word to create document output. Using Office 2010 this runs fast. Using Office 365 it is painfully slow. So a report that previously took 15 minutes now takes up to two hours. Client is not happy.

I have investigated this in considerable depth and attempted all mods that have been suggested, inc.

- Configuring trusted locations, for Word and Access
- Removing any addins from Word
- Unchecking any non essential Word features, such as spelling or grammer checks

As an example of a command that takes an excessive amount of time

```
Dim TaskImage As Word.Shape

Set TaskImage = mobjWordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(sFilePath, False, True, , , , , mRng)
TaskImage.top = 0
```

This one command can take 6 seconds to be completed.

I've tried difference combinations of software, and concluded the issues are down to the version of Word being used.

Can anyone sugggest any reasons why more recent versions of Word exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know anything that would cause a simple command such as you mention to take 6 seconds. Does this slow-down happen on multiple devices (if your client has multiple to test on) or only one? You've covered a few of the usual things to try, could also: ensure the Word document is first actually saved when you are working on it (ie in a trusted location as you note); use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Options.Pagination = False` (reset both to initial values when your code has completed) ... but these are never going to reduce 6 seconds to 'blazing fast'!!

Comment: How large (pages + file size) is your document? Is it in compatibility mode? -- The code snippet you posted doesn't do anything without setting `TaskImage` to an actual object. How is that done?

Comment: But all that being said, you are not the first person to notice that O365 is slower than O2010. There may not be much you can do besides optimizing as best as possible.

Comment: It's true the file can get big - 500 pages +. I've noted performance is not too bad for the first 200 pages, after that it starts to slow down a bit. But even with small reports, performance is only 25% of Office 2010.  Integrating with Word 16 processing just seems to hang at certain points, and takes several seconds to get going again.

Comment: Integration with Excel is not affected, issue does seem peculiar to Word

Comment: You use this `AddPicture` as an example, are you comparing Word 2010 and Office 365 when the same picture is inserted? Couldn't it be that the picture of running 365 is much bigger? Would it take so long to insert the same picture in Office 365 alone( without running the integrating code)?